# Persistent header and side-bars across multiple web-pages

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website I eventually plan on purchasing a domain for and having, hopefully, many users. Of course, a lot of people plan on that and it never comes true! Regardless, I'm progressing forward with the intent of having a good looking interface that's efficient in it's data usage.

One thing I would very much like to do is to have my banner / header and side-bars persist when they navigate to separate pages inside my site. My header contains the site-wide context menu as well as login and profile information, and the side-bars are currently undecided, but potentially just static images.

I don't know exactly how I would do it well. I could just use my PHP session object, but I'd like to be as efficient as possible.

I'm using a traditional LAMP stack, HTML, JS and CSS (using the Bootstrap library) on Ubuntu on an Amazon's EC2 service.

Comment: By persistent, meaning having the same content listed; got it. So, use `include()` where you want the same files to be included and in the spot you want it to be. Unless, there's something I'm not grasping here.

Comment: Nope, that's it exactly. I'm not entirely sure I understand how the data would be handled, though. Would you include it in my first page, fill the data and then when you navigate to other pages that also have it included it would keep the data from the first page?

Comment: In order for data to be passed from multiple pages (*including back & forth*), it's best to use [**sessions**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). Yet by "fill the data", you plan on having user input or data fetched?

Comment: The idea is that there would be a login field on the header that is replace with the profile information once the user has logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a file with header and sidebar and then use this php code:

```
include("nameofthefile.php");
```

on every file of your site

Comment: Is this some kind of in-line include or similar to normal includes that are put at the top of the file?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood: do you mean, for example, in-line css inclusion or javascript inclusion?

Comment: I mean would you include the file as you would a C header file. That's the only style of including that I'm aware of, but the comment by Fred suggests another way.

Comment: I don't know C yet, sorry. If you want to keep some data, you have to include the file and insert into it a code which saves the data into a session (as Fred suggested you) or a cookie

Comment: I make heavy usage of sessions already, so that should be easy. Thanks!